# Configure and access AngularJS $scope by a third party application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing an AngularJS application and I would like to integrate some functions to let an other web-application interact with the application. My application should run and triggered on the same website. Iframes are **not** used.

The application has several tabs, and I would like to set a tab active by specifying it's id.

This has been done in an AngularJS controller, through this method:

```
$scope.setActiveTab = function(tabId) {
    ribbon.setActiveTab(tabId);

    $scope.$apply();
}
```

In my application, I have a `ng-click` attribute and this function is being called in it. But now, I do want a other application to set the active tab by calling some JavaScript function.

Therefore, I've written the following function:

```
$.fn.OfficeUI.EnableTab = function(element) {
    angular.element($('#OfficeUI')).scope().setActiveTab('tabSendReceive');
}
```

However, this doesn't work, but when I past this method:

```
angular.element($('#OfficeUI')).scope().setActiveTab('tabSendReceive');
```

in the developer console of FireBug or Google Chrome, then it's working.

Any idea on what's wrong and how I should solve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you right. You need a application which allows developers (as you said `Users` :) to interact and configure your application by using HTML/JavaScript. Checkout this [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OpIZKbGzhspqiOZGU3Ui?p=preview).

A good approach is to do this with configuration files, global object, or events bindings. The following example shows you, how to let a user configure an a global config object in JavaScript & allows developers to interact with your application. For example by using `$scopes`.

Controller with global configuration object:

```
/**
   * Active state holder
   * @type {null|integer} 
   */ 
  var myConfig = {
    menus : {
      mainbar: {
        active: true
      },
      subbar: {
        active: false
      },
      othersubbar: {
        active: false
      }
    }
  };

var OfficeUIRibbon = angular.module('OfficeUIRibbon', [])

OfficeUIRibbon.factory('OfficeUIRibbonFactory', [function() {

      return {
        setActiveTabId: function (tabId) {
          activeTabId = tabId;
        }
      }
}]); 

OfficeUIRibbon.controller('OfficeUIRibbon', ['$scope', '$http', '$animate', function($scope, $http, $animate) {

    //as scope set
    $scope.isVisible = function (name){
      if (myConfig.menus[name].active) {
        return 'active';
      }
    } 

    $scope.activateMenu = function (name) {
      console.log(name);
      if (!myConfig.menus[name].active) {
       myConfig.menus[name].active = true;
      }
    }

    $scope.deactivateMenu = function (name) {
      if (myConfig.menus[name].active) {
       myConfig.menus[name].active = false;
      }
    }


    $scope.listing =  {
        mainbar: {
          id: 1,
          label: 'mainbar'
        },
        subbar: {
          id: 2,
          label: 'subbar'
        }, 
        othersubbar: {
          id: 3, 
          label: 'othersubbar'
        }  
    }
}]);
```

HTML-Template:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="OfficeUIRibbon">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,list) in listing" ng-class="isVisible(key)">
      {{ list.label }}
    </li> 
  </ul>

  <button ng-click="activateMenu('mainbar');">Activate Mainmenu</button>
  <button ng-click="deactivateMenu('mainbar');">Deactivate Mainmenu</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

User configuration, should be set before angular was loaded. For example, disable `mainbar` on default:

```
myConfig.menus.mainbar.active = false;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your work, but can you tell me why It isn't working when I do it on a click event, and not on a ng-click? I mean that the folllwing code does not work: <a href="#" on-click="myConfig.menus[1].mainbar.active = false;">Activate Mainmenu</a>

Comment: "on-click" is not valid attribute. But, if you using "onclick" it will not trigger your `$scope`, cause "onclick"-event is not watched by angular itself.

Comment: And it there any way to let angular watch for that event aswell? Because, Let's say that my user have a div element and when they click on it, a tab element should be showed, how should I accomplish that?

Comment: The user should insert `ng-click="activateMenu('mainbar');"`instead of using native Events (onclick). Its such the same, its a attribute which key is different, but same procedure. It is as broad as it is long.

Comment: I do have an additional question here. In my body, I'm still referencing the controller here. Isn't it needed to execute all this outside of my controlleR?

Comment: This question makes no sence. ;) Outside? Its dark outside.

Comment: I mean. Have a controller on the body and another one on an element inside. It's in this controller that my function is defined and I want to call it from outside that controller. I do have access to the controller on the body but that doesn't have the method. I thought services would do the trick but I don't manage to solve it. Of you want I can create a plunker.

Comment: Open up a new question please and build an plunker... of course, come in: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69567/discussion-between-complexity-and-lin

Comment: I will. But first. Dinner time.

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below that should helps you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.test = function(msg) {


    $scope.$apply(function() {

      $scope.msg = msg

    })

  }

});






$(function() {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#contoller')).scope().test("Message for Angular from jQuery");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 
  <div id="contoller" ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    {{msg}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's not what I was looking for. It's working when you call if from within a button, but not when using inside a SCRIPT tag. What if I want to call that method from within a script tag?

Comment: wow, this is cool ! I don't know SO allows you do things like this.

Comment: @Complexity what do you means by from inside script tag... please see above I've amended  a bit answer

Comment: Hmm, My code does work right now when I put an alert as the first statement, then the 2nd one is executed aswell. Otherwise it isn't. Any clues?

Comment: @Complexity .. no idea where is your's 1st and 2nd statement can you please update code

Comment: Hmm. Not on the pc anymore. But you run the function in the controller. I want the function to execute from within the HTML. So I have an app, and I want to expose an API to be called by my customer. For example from within the html. How should I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
$scope.apply(function(){
angular.element($('#OfficeUI')).scope().setActiveTab('tabSendReceive');
})
```

You are in jquery scope you must have to use $scope.apply to reflect it to angular.

Comment: This give me a $scope is not defined. Which seems to make sense. I don't know the variable $scope.

Comment: $.fn.OfficeUI.EnableTab  is not in your controller ..??

Comment: If I put it in my controller then I get an ' $.fn.OfficeUI.EnableTab is not a function' error.

Comment: try to put $scope as a dependency in the function don't put it inside the controller.
Like:-
$.fn.OfficeUI.EnableTab = function(element,$scope) {
    angular.element($('#OfficeUI')).scope().setActiveTab('tabSendReceive');
}

Comment: But how should it be called then? Sorry but I quite don't understand.